# how to rewind to the beginning of a line while reading from a file. c

Tags: c, file

other than counting how many spaces i moved. is there a simple way to get the buffer back to the beginning of a line for reading? am trying to read in strings and then go back to read a different string and numbers. its not in order so i have to go back and look for them specifically. how do i do it.

i use `rewind(fp);` but that goes back to the beginning of the file.

also am trying to read in integers after the strings. the problem is its hard to read in double, triple digit numbers. i was able to do. but as you see the function down there is a mess. is there an easier way to read multi-digit integers;

```
void get_total(FILE*fp, int* ptotal, int* pscores, int* pnum_quiz){

    char c;

    int i = 0;

    int total=0;

    int digits; 
    int first, second, third;

    *pnum_quiz = 0;

    int number_of_conversions;

    number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);

    while (isdigit(c) || isspace(c) && c !='\n' && c !=NULL && number_of_conversions!=0 && number_of_conversions !=EOF){


        if (isspace(c)){
            number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);

        }

        else if (isdigit(c)){
            first = c - '0'; // convert a character integer to integer

            *(pscores + i) = first;
            i++;

            number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);

            digits = 1;

            if (isdigit(c)){

                second = c - '0';

                *(pscores + i) = second;

                i++;

                number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);

                digits = 2;

                if (isdigit(c)){

                    third = c - '0';

                    *(pscores + i) = third;
                    i++;

                    digits = 3;
                }
                else{
                    fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
                    *(pscores + i) = -1;
                    i++;
                }


            }
            else{
                fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
                *(pscores + i) = -1;
                i++;
                *(pscores + i) = -1;
                i++;
            }

            if (digits==3){
                total = total + (first * 100) + (second * 10) + third;
            }
            else if (digits==2){
                total = total + (first * 10) + second;
            }
            else {
                total = total + first;
            }


            number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);



        } 

        number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);

        *pnum_quiz = *pnum_quiz + 1;
    }

    *ptotal = total;

}
```

Comment: Record the  file pointer position using `long offset = ftell(fp);` before you start ripping into your line, then `fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);`. Or did I utterly misunderstand the purpose?

Comment: In C, a text file is just a sequence of characters, and the beginning of a line is just where a newline character happens to be found in the file. (Actually, just _after_, of course.) There is no special way of rewinding to that place, so you need to either store the position, or search to find it. There could be operating systems that have additional functionality for this, but not any I know of.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Why not make this an answer?

Comment: Maybe you should entirely rethink the way you treat your problem.

Comment: @alk Been a long week. I concur with Michael on this. A different approach is probably warranted, and if thought out, going to be considerably more elegant.

Comment: whozcraig. thanks. it works.

Answer (score 2):

You could go `fseek`ing backwards through the file, but that's not a good option, in my opinion.

Just read in the whole line and store it in a `char` buffer. Your code does that with repeated calls to `fscanf(fp, "%c", &c)`, which is needlessly clumsy. There is already a function that does this, `fgets`:

```
char line[80];

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
    // Now scan line instead of fp
}
```

Now you can parse `line` depending on your iput format: `sscanf(line, ..)` if you have a fixed format. `strtok` repeatedly if you need to extract tokens, and so on. (You don't show the format of your input, but there's probably a function to deal with it better than coding it by hand.)

One potential problem with `fgets` is that you need to specify a maximum length, which may not be suitable if you can have arbitrarily long lines. There's also the annoyance of the new-line character that's left at the end of each line.